# Simple operator overload in D language throws exception

Tags: exception, operator-overloading, d

This code:

```
class C 
{
    int opAdd(C b) { return 1; }
    private int j;
}

void main() 
{
    C a;
    C c;

    int j = a + c;
}
```

Throws:

```
"object.Exception: Access Violate - Read at address 0x0"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Classes](http://dlang.org/class.html) in D are reference types. You need to instantiate them:

```
C a = new C();
C b = new C();
```

Also, `opAdd` has been replaced by `opBinary!"+"` in D2 (see [D2 operator overloading](http://dlang.org/operatoroverloading.html#Binary)).

Comment: Thanks!  How would you put a class instance on the stack?

Comment: Using [`emplace`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#emplace) from `std.conv`, or the [`scoped`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#scoped) template from `std.typecons`.

Comment: @DanDonnelly Post a separate question if you want a detailed answer for that. There are ways to do it, but normally you don't. They really don't belong there normally.